# Access denied in Linux Xampp

Tags: php, html, xampp

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I'm new to Linux platform. I tried to run xampp in my browser. It showed the message "Access Denied". Please tell me how to run a php file in Linux using xampp.

Comment: Can you please describe in detail the steps you took to 'run xampp in your browser'.

Answer (score 0):

1. check if you have php php5 ... installed if not apt-get
2. check if apache2 is running if you are not sure service apache2 restart
3. also chmod -R 777 the directory of your project
4. edit  xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.c­onf  and at the last paragraph change

   ```
   Deny from all
   ```

   to

   ```
   allow from all
   ```